# Perl Incorrect day generated by localtime

Tags: perl

Today I find following perl script running incorrect.
Current actual datetime is 20140814 13:19
But it returns: 2014-7-14-13-19-15 (the month value 7 is 1 less than actual value 8)

MY OS: win7

```
sub GetFileNameDate {
    my ($sec,$min,$hour,$day,$month,$yr19,@rest) =   localtime;
    return sprintf "%s-%s-%s-%02d-%02d-%02d", ($yr19 + 1900), $month, $day, $hour, $min, $sec;
}
```

Comment: Where's the mistake? Is it the month? Because if it is, it's correct (month is 0..11, not 1..12, see http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html).

Comment: When a function returns a value that you suspect to be wrong, surely the most obvious next step to take is to read the documentation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does perl's localtime seem to output the wrong month?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33676711/why-does-perls-localtime-seem-to-output-the-wrong-month)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not incorrect it is like the month values starts from 0

```
sub GetFileNameDate {
    my ($sec,$min,$hour,$day,$month,$yr19,@rest) =   localtime;
    return sprintf "%s-%s-%s-%02d-%02d-%02d", ($yr19 + 1900), ($month +1), $day, $hour, $min, $sec;
}
```

$month is the month itself, in the range 0..11 with 0 indicating January and 11 indicating December.

You can check the [manual](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html)

Answer (score 4):

That is correct according to the docs for [`localtime`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html):

> `$mday` is the day of the month and **`$mon` the month in the range `0..11`**, with 0 indicating January and 11 indicating December. This makes it easy to get a month name from a list.

However, to simplify your goal, I'd recommend using [`Time::Piece`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;

sub GetFileNameDate {
    return localtime->strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S");
}

print GetFileNameDate(), "\n";
```

Outputs:

```
2014-08-13-23-42-56
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you perhaps want `POSIX::strftime`?

```
use POSIX qw( strftime );

print strftime "%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S", localtime;
```